# Swift : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Entity name must not be nil.'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to implement CoreData with my existing swift project. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codebeaulieu.com/10/adding-core-data-using-swift-2) and implemented it with UITableView.

The data is getting added contentiously to the data model (from another view controller) when I am fetching data model record (in another view controller).

**Problem**

Navigating to the View Controller with UITableView, shows data from data model once. Tapping on the tableView or sliding it up or down causing the application to crash with error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Entity name must not be nil.'

**Function for saving record :**

```
func saveData(date: String, usr : String, piid: String, healthD:String, temp:String, humd:String) {
        //1
        let managedContext = DataController().managedObjectContext

        //2
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Hygeine",
            inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        let health = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        //3
        health.setValue(date, forKey: "date")
        health.setValue(healthD, forKey: "health")
        health.setValue(temp, forKey: "temp")
        health.setValue(humd, forKey: "humd")
        health.setValue(piid, forKey: "pi_id")
        health.setValue(usr, forKey: "usr")
        //4
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            //5
            healthData.append(health)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

**ViewWillAppear for ViewController with UITableView :**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        let managedContext = DataController().managedObjectContext

        //2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Hygeine")

        //3
        do {
            let results =
            try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            healthData = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

There are a lot of Objective-C solution to this problem but how to solve it in Swift 2. What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you ever considered using NSFetchedResults controller and its delegates instead of array ??? That will solve your issue I believe :)

Comment: Can you suggest me a tutorial as I am new to iOS development ? @SandeepBhandari

Comment: I have gone through this tutorial four years ago :) so it was in objective c :) https://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller Have a look at it very nicely explained :) most of the methods in swift are same :) so shouldnt be any issue to cope up :)

Comment: Thank you! I got few tutorials about NSFetchedResultsController with Swift. I will try with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entityForName` returns an optional that you are force unwrapping.  That is most likely your error and easily caught in the debugger.

Is your entity name entered wrong?  Check it against your model.

And as others have said, learn `NSFetchedResultsController`, while it won't solve this error, it is easier to work with when dealing with a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Entity name was right. NSFetchedResultsController helped to update the UITableView as the new data object is added. Thank you!